# Stack overflow on recursive call of a function

Tags: c++, function, recursion, stack-overflow

I am trying to make a strand sort algorithm and when I try to recursive call it again it gives me stack overflow error

The recursive call is where I want to sort array a into two sorted arrays(preme, NoNpreme). And after that I merge these to back into a.
I have tried to mess around with conditions and I figured out that array is sorted when there is only 1 element and that is my exit for recursion. But it doesn't work and I do not know why.

My algorithm:

```
int* urediSPrameni(int* a, int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return a;

    int pe=a[0];
    int* preme = new int[n];
    preme[0] = a[0];
    int j = 1;
    int k = 0;
    int* NoNpreme = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > pe)
        {
            pe = a[i];
            preme[j] = a[i];
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            NoNpreme[k] = a[i];
            k++;
        }
    }
    NoNpreme = urediSPrameni(NoNpreme, k);


    // My merge algorithm:

    //Zlivanje
    int h = 0;//NoNpreme
    int s = 0;//Preme
    int i = 0;
    while (h < k && s < j)
    {
            if (preme[h] <= NoNpreme[s])
            {
                a[i] = preme[h];
                s++;
            }
            else
            {
                a[i] = NoNpreme[s];
                h++;
            }
            i++;
    }
    if (h > k)
    {
        for (int b = s;b < j;b++)
        {
            a[i] = NoNpreme[b];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int b = h;b < k;b++)
        {
            a[i] = preme[b];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

I call function like this:

```
int n = 7;
int drek[] = { 5,1,2,20,5,28,7 };
int* urejenoZap = urediSPrameni(drek, n);
for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    cout << urejenoZap[i] << " ";
system("PAUSE");
```

Where `drek` is unsorted and `urejenoZap` is pointer to sorted array `drek`.

Comment: `NoNpreme = urediSPrameni(NoNpreme, k);` should be `return urediSPrameni(NoNpreme, k);`

Comment: And it leaks a lot of memory because you don't `delete[]` the memory you allocate with `new[]`.

Comment: O.K. so I deleted the arrays 1 line before return and put return NoNpreme = urediSPrameni(NoNpreme, k) but it still over flows.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think that the merge part is the continuation of the same function.  THe return at this place would cause the rest of the function to never be reached.

Comment: So how do I repair this?

Comment: @robi there's a lot of broken things here.  You quickly comme to a point where your pivot (the first item of the array) is smaller or equal to every item in the list.  But then you keep invoking recursively the algorithm (with the same list):  https://ideone.com/9Qr2Xt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the first element of `a` to `pe`, and store a copy of that element into `preme`.  When sorting the elements of `a` into separate arrays based on which side of `pe` they fall on, you start with element 0 again (which you've already placed into `preme`), which, because `if (a[i] > pe)` will be *false*, will place this element into `NoNpreme`.  Once the array reaches the point where there is more than one element, and the first element is the smallest, *all* of the elements will be copied into `NoNpreme`.  Each recursive call after that will do the same, so the recursion will never end and you'll eventually run out of stack space.

The solution is to start your for loop with the second element:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
```